# PHP stream wrapper for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, prestashop, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am in a process of setting up Prestashop installation in a cluster of 3 GCE instances, managed by Kubernetes. I use Cloud SQL as DB and all seems to be running well, except, of course the images part, since prestashop in each pod uploads and shows images to/from it's local filesystem.

In App Engine I cloud use stream_context_set_default() and that would allow me to use "gs://mybucket" as a regular path. Is there a way to do that in Compute Engine? If it is possible, making Prestashop use Cloud Storage bucket can be done in 2 lines of code.

There is a StreamWrapper for Amazon S3 service that does exactly what I need: http://hiousi.tumblr.com/post/94824087894/prestashop-images-hosted-on-amazon-s3
But I would like to use Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the stream wrapper can be downloaded at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk/tree/master/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams.

It has a couple of dependencies on other GAE APIs such as App Identity & Urlfetch. They may need to be stubbed out or replaced by equivalent services on GCE.

Answer (score -1):

i have created a PHP StreamWrapper for Google Compute Engine, if you're still interested. Here is the link to my adapted version.
https://github.com/jimyaghi/GCECloudStorageStreamWrapper

Sorry it's not more friendly, but it's a good useful bit of work. i'm using it and it works great.